# How to filter an interface using conditional types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a type that takes an interface as a generic type parameter and filters out properties whose values are not strings.

This is what I have:

```
interface Bla {
    key1: string;
    key2: number;
    key3: string;
    key4: boolean;
}

type PickStrings<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends string ? T[K] : never;
}

const bla: PickStrings<Bla> = { // should error as key3 is not present 
    key1: 'string',
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIBs7IN4ChkHIDWEAngIwBcyAzmFKAOYDc%20hJpATNSAK4C2AI2itCxMgGZqdBiBZsCHACzVBAezXoIcEKwC%20uXGFIAHFAAVgCIgGV6TGgB4AKgD5kAXhwLkAbQDSyKDipGowyM4AugD81M4BkcgQAB6QIAAmNLT2csjREQnIPBAAbiK4BrgIaiB0yIKY1JbWdrKMThhw7l7YyAD0fbQAFmq86OlJUFBqUMhwWRwSQVkgamDIJlAQNBDgyD4cVMgA5DJMxwA0FUA)

The problem with using `[K in keyof T]?` is it doesn't error as keys become optional. But, if I use `[K in keyof T]` it is checking for the existence of all keys in the interface.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a type to extract the keys by type and then use it with `Pick`

```
type PickKeysByValueType<T, TYPE> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends TYPE ? K : never
}[keyof T]

type PickStrings<T> = Pick<T, PickKeysByValueType<T, string>>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7&ssl=12&ssc=62&pln=8&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIBs7IN4ChkHIDWEAngIwBcyAzmFKAOYDc+hJpATNSAK4C2AI2itCxMgGZqdBiBZsCHACzVBAezXoIcEKwC+uXGFIAHFAAVgCIgGkyNVKQBqcdLwgAVUxAA8HgDTIHgCa5gCiAHzIALw4CsgA2jbIoOKkajBBALrUHklZyBAAHpAgACY0QaFhyAD8yMk8EABu0Lh6CRwZ2YbGZsiW1gDK9Ew0flGxg0R+gdN2pA7Oru5eZrO0o3IREYYIaiB0yIKY1NMjsozjGHCTOMgA9A+0ABZqvOhlhVBQalDIcEqHAkKUqIDUYGQJigEBoEHAyHiHCoyAA5DImKj2kA)